# ASP.net webservice security preventing WndProc & run with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis

I have a webservice with a couple of methods that attempt to run or message another .EXE on the system to do a specific task.

Either we can start the .EXE process with certain parameters or send it a WndProc message to make it do the desired operation. This works fine locally on my system calling the exe with parameters in cmd or sending a WndProc message from the webservice when debugging it in Visual Studio.

None of this works over a real environment however. I had the run .Exe with parameters method (DoSomething) write the exception to a file:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): No Access
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
at Someprogram.ProgramService.DoSomething(String text)
```

The other method for wndproc sendmessage I wrapped in a try/catch as well but no exception thrown. It actually locates the process though as I had it print a file:

```
public static void SendMessageToSomeProgram(string message) {
      Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("SomeProgram");
      if (processes.Length >= 1) {
        //iterate through all running target applications
        foreach (Process p in processes) {
          //test write if process found
          TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\wndprocfile.txt"); //this file is printed
          tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
          tw.Close();
          //do stuff
          try {
            byte[] sarr = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(message);
            int len = sarr.Length;
            COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
            cds.dwData = (IntPtr)100;
            cds.lpData = message;
            cds.cbData = len + 1;
            SendMessage(p.MainWindowHandle, WM_COPYDATA, 0, ref cds);
          } catch (Exception ex) {
            TextWriter tw2 = new StreamWriter(@"c:\wndProc_errorfile.txt"); //not printed
            tw2.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "Exception: " + ex.ToString());
            tw2.Close();
          }
       }
}
```

Now I see why it's nice to have security like this in place but is there an easy way around this? Maybe just some settings in IIS?

UPDATED INFO: The server is running IIS 5.1 so no Application Pool feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service inside IIS runs as the user connected to the app pool it's running as. So try to change the user of the app pool to a user that have access to start the application you want to start up.

To do this, check the applications app pool and then go to the app pool and change the user. To change the user you have to turn pass-through authentication off.

Comment: The host computer is running IIS 5.1 so pretty outdated (that and earlier version doesn't have application pools as a feature: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525832(v=vs.90).aspx). I can recommend the server responsible to upgrade but in any case that's not something that will happen anytime soon I suspect.

Comment: What about going about it the other way then it you can't change the web server user: Giving the user that runs the web app permissions to start the app.

Comment: Adding <identity impersonate="true" /> to System.Web in the web.config file is a step in the right direction it seems (so it doesn't use the default ASPNET account but rather the logged in Windows user). The external .EXE gets called but it crashes for some reason (it works fine being called from CMD/RUN).

Comment: Small update: No further progress. Allowing the IIS Admin service desktop access had no positive effect. This blog alludes that there's some underlying Windows security properties not exposed to .Net that might be the cause: http://asprosys.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/perils-and-pitfalls-of-launching.html